# Determine which custom HTML tag is offending IE8

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

We're using a ton of custom tags in our angular.js app, and I'm trying to get IE8 to recognize them all.  The setup:

- Angular (1.1.5)
- HTML5 mode
- Using custom tags for directives in many cases (and we aren't `R`eplacing them)
- Using IE-shiv.js to register the custom tags with IE8

It's a big app - we are registering 50+ custom tags in IE in IE-shiv.js (we like how legible the markup is with custom tags). I've been through the app several times, looking for tags I forgot to register, but I am still getting `Error: Unexpected call to method or property access.undefined`. I'm currently turning parts of the app on and off to find the offending tag... but it feels like there might be a better way:

**Can I detect which custom HTML tag triggered the error in IE8?** Is there some sneaky way - monkey-punching document.createElement or adding a try/catch to some internal angular directive, perhaps?

Comment: I vaguely think you want an XML file with styling...

Comment: it's worth pointing out that the HTML5 spec explicitly says *not* to use custom tags due to potential conflicts with future actual HTML tags that may be introduced. There is a custom tag spec currently being developed, which would require custom tags to begin with `x-` to avoid that conflict, but it's not been finalised yet.

Comment: WRT future tagname conflicts: one approach to minimize likelihood down to nearly zero is to always prefix directive name, as angular's core directives do: `ng-view`, `ng-repeat`, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run this JS once the document is loaded. It will will find all elements with a tag name that starts with a `/` character, which is created in IE8 for all unrecognised elements when the parser encounters the close tag.

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len ; i++) {
  if (list[i].tagName.indexOf('/') === 0)
    alert(list[i].tagName.substr(1));
}
```

Comment: Exactly the kind of thing I was hoping to learn.  A little tricky to run the check on asynchronously loaded DOM elements, but helpful.

Comment: In the Alohci code, you can replace 'alert' by 'document.createElement' if you want to fix all your custom  tag issu in ie < 9 . You can 
read more on : http://ajaxian.com/archives/adding-custom-tags-to-internet-explorer-the-official-way

Comment: thank you - thank you - I thought I removed all the custom elements - but with this script I just did another check and ... I've missed one...

Answer (score 1):

I have had this happen with directives. I built some custom directives and was using restrict: "AE". I had then used the directive in the HTML as an element, for example:

```
 <my-directive>
```

I changed the directive to use an attribute and it is working.

```
 <div my-directive>
```

In short, IE doesn't recognize the new elements. There are tricks to getting this to work, but I have just avoided the elements and have been using attributes. Hopefully your issue is this simple, otherwise IE8 might make you stab yourself in the eyes!!!

Comment: I'd like to keep using the tagName directly - that's why we are using IE-shiv.js to pre-register all the custom tags - see: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/tree/master/common/ieshiv

Comment: Sure, but I am saying that it is worth checking as that is the error message that I received in IE when using the tagName directly..